# Dropbear authentication error | No auth methods could be used

Tags: embedded-linux, dropbear, dbclient

I am tyring to ssh to a remote server using `dropbear` from my embedded board (with custom `Linux` distribution built using `yocto`). By deafult the `dropbear` ssh client is used instead of `openssh` client. When I try to establish connection I get

```
ssh: Connection to device@example.com:22 exited: No auth methods could be used.
```

ssh command I am using:

```
ssh -i <>/.ssh/id_ecdsa -p 22 -R <remote_port>:localhost:22 device@example.com
```

The <>/.ssh/id_ecdsa private key is generated using

```
dropbearkey -f /home/root/.ssh/id_ecdsa -t ecdsa -b 256
```

Also, I have added pub key to `authorized_keys` in `/home/root/.ssh/` with

```
dropbearkey -y -f id_ecdsa | grep "^ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 " >> authorized_keys
```

Can anyone please let em know what is the issue here and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

P.S: Please let me know if any info is missing here

Comment: Hey there; I've read that dropbear uses a different key format than openssh; so perhaps your key might need to be converted with `dropbearconvert`?  e.g., `dropbearconvert dropbear openssh ./id_rsa ./id_rsa_openssh` .  ... 

I read this here: https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access  ... hope this helps.

Comment: I see you are running `dropbearkey -f` to get your pub key, but I think it might need to be additionally converted?  Not sure.